# Use Post Method to send XML Parameter

Tags: php, xml, curl

I wonder if somebody could help me out with this - I have been trying for a few hours and no joy. When this is submitted I get an error message that says "Use POST method to send XML paramater". I thought I was doing this but obviously not. Any pointers are much appreciated. Obviously the Username, Password and URL are different on the live version

```
define('XML_PAYLOAD', '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Request><Head><Username>myusername</Username><Password>mypassword</Password><RequestType>HotelSearch</RequestType></Head><Body><HotelIds><HotelId>2234836</HotelId></HotelIds><CheckInDate>2017-05-01</CheckInDate><CheckOutDate>2017-05-08</CheckOutDate><Rooms><Room><NumAdults>2</NumAdults></Room></Rooms><Nationality>GB</Nationality><Currency>GBP</Currency><AvailableOnly>0</AvailableOnly></Body></Request>');
define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://theurl');
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
$start = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$stop = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$totalTime = $stop - $start;
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 404:
            $result = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
echo 'Total time for request: ' . $totalTime . "\n";
echo $result;   
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add content type with your request header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
```

Or may be `text/xml` or whatever the server is accepting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sabuj. I have tried that and also with 'text/xml' as suggested and also 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' but am still getting the same error

Comment: You can add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`. It will generate curl's debug print and using that you can trace further.

Comment: Thanks Sabuj. I will give that a go